# Is it possible to deprecate a C/C++ function without forward declarations in GCC?

Tags: gcc, deprecated

I would like to deprecate some function calls to a large code-base without making many disruptive changes (adding a deprecation header to every file for e.g.).

Using `-include` (command line argument) it's possible to deprecate functions without modifying the source, however this raises the problem that every function needs to be declared. For a large portable code-base this isn't trivial (see example below).

The problem with having to forward declare functions is the types need to match exactly (including attributes), and all types need to be available.

Deprecating `strncpy` for e.g. means `size_t` needs to be available, causing the deprecation header to include a header defining `size_t`, causing deprecation to pull in definitions not intended to be accessed from the source files.

Is there a way to deprecate API calls without having to forward declare functions?

---

This header deprecates `strcat` it works with GCC/CLANG/MSVC.

```c
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define _DEPRECATE_ATTR __attribute__((deprecated))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#  define _DEPRECATE_ATTR __declspec(deprecated)
#else
#  define _DEPRECATE_ATTR
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#  define _DEPRECATE_CXX_NOEXCEPT noexcept
#else
#  define _DEPRECATE_CXX_NOEXCEPT
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

_DEPRECATE_ATTR
extern char *strcat(char *, const char *)
#ifndef _MSC_VER
    _DEPRECATE_CXX_NOEXCEPT
#endif
    ;

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

---

NOTE: poisoning could work too, however poisoning from an `-include`  causes the function declarations from system headers to raise an error.

Comment: Regarding your problem, I would argue that the cleanest way is to have your deprecation macro in a "god header file" that is included anywhere you need to deprecate a function. Then edit each and every header file containing declarations that should be deprecated. If it's spread out over many files (typical of older systems when things starts to be added without proper design) it's a lot of work if you want to do it all at once. But it is a one-time change, that hopefully won't need to be repeated very often.

Comment: @some-programmer-dude of course this can be handled by convention. The advantage of deprecating / poisoning is there is one less thing to have to manually remind developers not to use... message them if someone accidentally accepts a PR which includes API calls which should not be used.